# Java getName of obj that activated MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I have a problem with my project. My problem is that I don't know how to get name of the label which has been activated by the MouseListener?

MouseListener works, and now I just need to get the name of the label which was activated by the mouselistener.

example

```
label1 = new JLabel("FirstLabel");
label1.addMouseListener(ml);
add(label1);    

label2 = new JLabel("SecondLabel");
label2.addMouseListener(ml);
add(label2);    

MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                otherLabel = // code to get labelname ( label1 or label2)

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks Clad Clad for edit. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for (not tested)?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
    String name = label.getText();
}
```

Sources:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName%28%29

Comment: Its not return name, but still works as I need, im very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Read the java docs:

```
public Component getComponent()
Returns the originator of the event.
Returns:
the Component object that originated the event, or null if the object is not a Component.
```